# How can I align this?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
R = \left(\begin{array}{cc} cos \theta & -sin\theta \\ sin\theta & cos\theta\end{array}\right) \hspace{45 pt}\mbox{The rotation matrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
yA = \left(\begin{array}{cc} ya & yb \\ yc & yd\end{array}\right) \hspace{45 pt}\mbox{Scaling $A$ by $y$}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I don't think anyone likes typing the code from your image...

Comment: I think this is the second question you are asking like this with a screen shot. Kindly consider posting minimal (but complete) code.

Comment: @someonr: it's more about finding the problem than it is solving it for me...but ok! :)

Comment: @Jossie *Please* use code tags and this isn't a MWE. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem (or finding it ;) ). It might also help to specify the question more exactly. Are you looking for an advice for formatting the formular?

Comment: @Jossie: What do you want to align? You just ask "How can I align this?" What does "this" refer to? The `=` signs?

Comment: Dear downvoters: Now that the OP has been revised, will you please consider reversing your downvotes? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lines of your example commented and changed for the more TeX-like behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%\begin{equation*}
\begin{align}
%R = \left(\begin{array}{cc} cos \theta & -sin\theta \\ sin\theta & cos\theta\end{array}\right) \hspace{45 pt}\mbox{The rotation matrix}
R &= \left(\begin{array}{rr} \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right) &\mbox{The rotation matrix}\\
%\end{equation*}
%\begin{equation*}
%yA = \left(\begin{array}{cc} ya & yb \\ yc & yd\end{array}\right) \hspace{45 pt}\mbox{Scaling $A$ by $y$}
yA &= \left(\begin{array}{cc} ya & yb \\ yc & yd\end{array}\right) 
&\mbox{Scaling $A$ by $y$}
%\end{equation*}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Explanation.* Separated equations have no kowledge of aligning of each other. When you choosee `amsmath` package, `align` & Co. is the main solution during aligning, as the name states.

If you want also to correct of vertical space between (1) and (2), you can try to use, e.g., `\\[6pt]` in the proper place.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to align at the `=`?

Comment: @SeanAllred Oh, oh! Correcting...

Comment: @SeanAllred Corrected. Thank you! To many changes = additional mistakes. :-(

Comment: `&&\mbox{...}` will left-align the contents therein. Also, isn't it easier to use `pmatrix` than `array`?

Comment: @KevinC You are right, but OP is rather a beginner. Proper usage of \cos, \sin and array will be enough.

Comment: @KevinC -- and `\text{...}`would be even better than `\mbox`.